# Why is SonarAnalyzer reporting 'Unused method parameters should be removed'?

Tags: c#, sonarlint

I am having an issue with SonarLint/Analyzer's (SonarAnalzer.CSharp (8.36.1.44192)) reporting of the ["Unused method parameters should be removed" (1172) rule](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-1172). I wish to know what I might be doing incorrectly here. The message from SonarSource is seemingly to generic and immediately confusing considering the actual use of the parameter, as seen below.

As far as research goes, I have read many other posts here about the same issue, all seemingly slightly different than my situation (many are for Java), where mine seems far more basic in its design. I also can not find an issue on SonarSource's site about this.

The report from SonarAnalzer, in Visual Studio, is on the single parameter: `CommunicationsQueueItem item`. This however seems erroneous as the value is used, so long as it is not null, as seen here (screenshot below):

```
private async Task<bool> Send(CommunicationsQueueItem item)
{
    var result = false;

    if (item != null)
    {
        if (item.Type == Core.Domain.Enums.CommunicationType.Email)
            result = await _emailProvider.SendEmail(
                    item.From, item.To, item.Cc, item.Bcc, item.Subject, item.Body
                );
        else
            result = await _psProvider.SendMessage(item.From, item.To, item.Subject, item.Body);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Changing the code to test for the possible null condition and return earlier allows the warning to go away, but it is fundamentally the same thing, just with an extra return statement:

```
private async Task<bool> Send(CommunicationsQueueItem item)
{
    var result = false;

    if (item == null) return result;

    if (item.Type == Core.Domain.Enums.CommunicationType.Email)
        result = await _emailProvider.SendEmail(
                item.From, item.To, item.Cc, item.Bcc, item.Subject, item.Body
            );
    else
        result = await _psProvider.SendMessage(item.From, item.To, item.Subject, item.Body);

    return result;
}
```

I appreciate the help, and look forward to the very simple or silly thing I am probably missing. Here is a screenshot of the reported issue in VS2022:
[image]

Comment: Can it be that it has deduced that there is no way it is ever passed in, or with the right type?

Comment: Well, without getting into some of DDD's design elements, yes, it should never be passed in without the right type. But even then I am not sure it would matter as it uses item.Type in the second condition, and therefore "item" is not ignored.

Comment: Use "Show potential fixes" and select one of the options to add an exception to the rule. It might be a #pragma, C# attribute, or even a change in the linting rules. There should be a preview for each option.

Comment: @jalepi - I was trying not to ignore the issue in that way, but rather, see if this was a bug in SonarAnalyzer or actually correct my issue in code. Seeing how the community has not pounced on the resolution of this issue though, that is most likely the solution, to ignore it.